# Kedro pipeline on partitioned data

Tags: kedro

I work on partitioned data (partitioned parquet or SQL table with a "partition" column). I want Kedro to load and save data from a partition I provide at runtime (e.g. kedro run --params partition:A). The number of partitions is large and dynamic.

I use Spark. Is there a way to load/save data the way I need with SparkDataSet or SparkJDBCDataSet?

Answer (score 0):

A quick google suggests the Spark JDBCDriver can use a timestamp column for [partitioning](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22814) . All Kedro does behind the scenes is pass the catlaog `load_args` and `save_args` to the native driver so this may work.

One another way to use a lifecycle [hook](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/07_extend_kedro/02_hooks.html) like `before_pipeline_run`, inspect the [run parameters](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kedro.framework.hooks.specs.PipelineSpecs.html#kedro.framework.hooks.specs.PipelineSpecshttps://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kedro.framework.hooks.specs.PipelineSpecs.html#kedro.framework.hooks.specs.PipelineSpecs) and then inject some custom logic at that point as you're able to inspect the `--params` run arguments easily at that point.

A last thought - if you subclass and extend the SQL dataset you want to use you can easily extend it to partition the way you want it. You won't easily be able to pass run `--params` but it would be easy to retrieve env variables or custom catalog arguments.